# When page loads, give me url - Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Whenever I load a webpage, I need to get the URL of the current tab to be stored in some variable. I would prefer, to get the URL of the website I am requesting, before anything loads, so I can do some logic depending on the URL.

What are the methods that I can use so I can achieve that?

(this is for firefox extension)

Comment: Have you read any documentation, of what data you can access about the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specifics of your task, three of the [how-tos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions#How_to) on the main MDN page on web extensions are relevant:

- [Intercepting HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) (`webRequest`)
- [Modify a web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page) (content scripts), and
- the [tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Working_with_the_Tabs_API) (specifically [`onUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated)).